Глобальный код в два раза медленнее локального
Почему код на уровне модуля исполняется в два раза медленнее такого же кода в функции?



global.py
local.py




s = 0for i in range(100_000_000):    s += iprint(s)
def main():    s = 0    for i in range(100_000_000):        s += i    print(s)main()


Десять секунд:
Против пяти:


$ time -p python global.py4999999950000000real 9.58user 9.56sys 0.00
$ time -p python local.py4999999950000000real 4.76user 4.75sys 0.00



Проверено на CPython 3.7, 3.10, 3.12.

python -m dis намекает, что получать доступ к гарантированно локальной переменной через LOAD_FAST видимо быстрее, чем искать глобальную переменную во всех подряд пространствах имён через LOAD_NAME

@andreymal Вот и оформили бы как ответ. Логично всё. )  В нормальных языках локальные переменные вообще на стеке лежат, ну и плюс утилизируются после выхода из блока кода, поэтому их так и любят. Ну, помимо принципа инкапсуляции.

А с Numba.njit вообще за 0.1с считает (если заранее Numba подгрузить и скомпилировать под ним функцию, а если на ходу, то 0.5с где-то с компиляцией вместе). Я как всегда о своём. И print(np.arange(100_000_000).sum()) - тоже 0.5с

@CrazyElf, кто бы сомневался. Понятно, что много есть способов считать. Я тут не давно писал один код, про факториалы. Всё сделал, да решил убрать функцию main. Она одна была, почти. Убрал. Хлоп! 45 секунд! Вернул, стало 30. Задумался. Вот вопрос задал. Но компилятор по разному комипилирует один и тот же код в разном окружении. Это шок. Никогда, никогда не писать глобальный код?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Для рисёрча писать, почему нет. Для продакшена, для скорости, и вообще для порядка - да, не использовать глобальные переменные, писать "чистые" функции, классы, разбивать на модули. И дело обычно не только в скорости, но и меньшей глючности, большей понятности кода и т.д.

Есть статья про это:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function/

Но если в файле global.py сделать функцию и вызвать ее, то, надеюсь, результат будет таким же, как с main? (но вообще, все это выглядит странным. Казалось бы, давно пора прикрутить jit)

@avp Так файлы только этим и отличаются вроде.

Why does Python code run faster in a function?.
